# bem css big confusion

Tags: html, css, bem

** writing multiple block on same element is right approach in BEM ? *

```
  <div class="block-1 block-2 block-1_modifier block-2_modifier">
       <div class="block-1__element1">
             <div class="block-1__element3 block-2__element2">
             </div>
       </div>
       <div class="block-1__element2">
           <div class="block-1__element4">
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is partially correct, although your naming convention above should be more like:

- block-1 **SHOULD NOT HAVE** block-2
- Your single nest level for block-1__element3 is good.

> Don't do **block-1__element2__element3**
> because that creates messy nesting.
> Only nest one level deep - like the example you indicated.
> This is a tidier approach to BEM which was overlooked by those who used it.

See corrections:

```
 <div class="block-1 block-1--modifier-1 block-1--modifier-2">
       <div class="block-1__element1">
       </div>
       <div class="block-1__element2">
           <div class="block-1__element3"> </div>
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: but why block-1 SHOULD NOT HAVE block-2 . plz check this link en.bem.info/forum/4 –

Comment: @samsam why would it? block1 is block1, not block2. Why complicate it with dual concept. Thats oo css. The two do not mix. Otherwise don't use bem, use oo css.